# Looking for intuition for why this inequality holds.

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $$u = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{z_{k}}{p^{k}}$$

where $p$ is a fixed natural number and $z_{k} \in \{0, 1, \dots, p-1\}$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, with the assumption that $z_{k} < p-1$ infinitely often.

I'm going through a proof, and the author casually says that it should be obvious that:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{z_{k}}{p^{k}} \leq u < \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{z_{k}}{p^{k}} + \frac{1}{p^{n}}$$

for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I've already confirmed that this is true, but I still don't see why this should be obvious. Is there something I'm overlooking?

**My reasoning:**

I reasoned it's true because $0 \leq u < 1$ and if we subtract across by $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{z_{k}}{p^{k}}$ and then multiply across by $p^{n}$, we get

$$0 \leq \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{z_{k}}{p^{k}} < \frac{1}{p^n}$$

which is true because even if we have $z_{k} = p-1$ for all $k$, the infinite sum is bounded by $1$ (geometric series).

**Is there a more intuitive reason for why this should be true?**

Comment: For the lower bound, it's enough to observe that $z_k/p^k$ is never negative and so a finite portion of the series can't exceed the infinite series.

Answer (score 0):

Lets look at the last inequality. For the sake of argument let us try and take the largest possible sum by assuming $z_k=p-1$ for all $k$.

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{z_k}{p^k}&=(p-1)\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{p^{k+n+1}}\\
&=\frac{p-1}{p^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{p^k}\\
&=\frac{p-1}{p^{n+1}}(\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{p}})\\
&=\frac{p-1}{p^{n+1}}(\frac{p}{p-1})\\
&=\frac{1}{p^n}
\end{align}
$$

Therefore you sum is always $0\leq\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{z_k}{p^k}\leq p^n$. The strict inequality comes from the fact that infinitely many of your terms $z_k<p-1$ as stated in your problem.